Django-Tables2 To Export Multiple Tables
I am working with Django-tables2 and Django to export multiple tables in 2 file. Is this possible? If so, how would it be done?
When I try, it gives me an as_values error.

Generally speaking, just export one after the other, zip them together before downloading, or use some sort of Javascript to download them separately.
It is difficult to say what issues your current effort is going through without seeing the code and errors.

@Ben, is there an example of zipping them together that you can provide? I can use TableExport to get each individually done, but zipping together to download all at once would solve it!

Use the TableExport.export method to grab the data, saving as individual files, then use Python's zipfile (https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) function to zip them together, and finally use an HttpResponse to serve up the zipfile.
https://github.com/jieter/django-tables2/blob/master/django_tables2/export/export.py#L86
